# Segement Control not working or not triggering any even in ios 14

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uisegmentedcontrol

I have UISegment control programatically created in objective C. It works perfectly fine in ios 12-13.2 and it suddenly stopped working in ios 14.Can someone tell me whats the work around for segement control in ios 14.

```
 CGRect segmentCtrlFrame = CGRectMake(20, 20, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width - 40, 30);
        UISegmentedControl *appUsageSegmentCtrl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc]initWithItems:self.appUsageOptionsArray];
        appUsageSegmentCtrl.frame = segmentCtrlFrame;
        [appUsageSegmentCtrl setTintColor:SEGMENT_CONTROL_COLOR];
        [appUsageSegmentCtrl addTarget:self action:@selector(appUsageChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        [cell addSubview:appUsageSegmentCtrl];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
        appUsageSegmentCtrl.selectedSegmentIndex = self.selectedAppUsage;
        if (@available(iOS 13, *)) {
             [appUsageSegmentCtrl setSelectedSegmentTintColor:SEGMENT_CONTROL_COLOR];
        }
        [appUsageSegmentCtrl setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blackColor]} forState: UIControlStateSelected];
```

Comment: Can you define "not working"? What behavior are you specifically experiencing?

Comment: Segement Control?

Comment: What's the guy named cell?

Comment: @Rob In ios 13 - 13.2 i can change the segment and select  index.But in ios 13.3 and higher we cant change the segment.I mean cant select segment.

Comment: @ElTomato Cell is tableview cell.Segement is included in table view cel.

Comment: To be precise addTarget is not triggered when we press the segment control

Comment: It would be simpler and easier if you use the segment control, not the segement control, with `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: For iOS 14 we need to add cell.contentview.isuserinteractionenabled = false and it worked